# Magento 2: How to override newsletter Subscriber model

Tags: magento2, overrides

I want to add 3 new fields in news letter popup for that i have written custom module. i am overriding Subscriber model and New Action Controller. But not able to call **subscribe** method of **subscriber** model.
and also getting error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Navin\Subscribe\Controller\Subscribe\NewAction::__construct() must
>   be an instance of Navin\Subscribe\Model\Subscriber, instance of
>   Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context given, called in
>   /var/www/html/jansport/var/generation/Navin/Subscribe/Controller/Subscribe/NewAction/Interceptor.php
>   on line 14 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/jansport/app/code/Navin/Subscribe/Controller/Subscribe/NewAction.php:33\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/jansport/var/generation/Navin/Subscribe/Controller/Subscribe/NewAction/Interceptor.php(14):
>   Navin\Subscribe\Controller\Subscribe\NewAction->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context),
>   Object(Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Session\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager),
>   Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Url),
>   Object(Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor))\n#1
>   /var/www/html/jansport/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93):
>   Navin\Subscribe in
>   /var/www/html/jansport/app/code/Navin/Subscribe/Controller/Subscribe/NewAction.php
>   on line 33

My code is:
di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction" type="Navin\Subscribe\Controller\Subscribe\NewAction" />
    <preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber" type="Navin\Subscribe\Model\Subscriber" />
</config>
```

NewAction.php Controller

```
    namespace Navin\Subscribe\Controller\Subscribe;

    //use Navin\Subscribe\Model\SubscriberFactory;

    class NewAction extends \Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction {

        /**
         * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
         */
        protected $subscriberFactory;

        public function __construct(
        \Navin\Subscribe\Model\Subscriber $subscriberFactory
        ) {
            $this->subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
        }

        public function execute() {

            //echo 'test come here';exit;
            $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            //var_dump($post);exit;

            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('email')) {
                $email = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
                $subscriber_name = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('subscriber_name');
                $subscriber_date_of_birth = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('subscriber_dateofbirth');
                $subscriber_country_code = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('subscriber_countrycode');
                $requestCatalog = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('requestCatalog');

                try {
                    $this->validateEmailFormat($email);
                    $this->validateGuestSubscription();
                    $this->validateEmailAvailable($email);

                    $status = $this->subscriberFactory->subscribe($email, $subscriber_name, $subscriber_date_of_birth, $subscriber_country_code);
                    if ($status == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The confirmation request has been sent.'));
                    } else {

                        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Thank you for your subscription.'));
                    }
                } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                    $this->messageManager->addException(
                            $e, __('There was a problem with the subscription: %1', $e->getMessage())
                    );
                } catch (\Exception $e) {

                    $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong with the subscription.'));
                }
            }

            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl());
        }

    }
```

Subscriber.php Model

```
namespace Navin\Subscribe\Model;

class Subscriber extends Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber {

    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function subscribe($email, $subscriber_name = '', $subscriber_date_of_birth = '', $subscriber_country_code = '') {

        $this->loadByEmail($email);

        if (!$this->getId()) {
            $this->setSubscriberConfirmCode($this->randomSequence());
        }

        $isConfirmNeed = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                        self::XML_PATH_CONFIRMATION_FLAG, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                ) == 1 ? true : false;
        $isOwnSubscribes = false;

        $isSubscribeOwnEmail = $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn() && $this->_customerSession->getCustomerDataObject()->getEmail() == $email;

        if (!$this->getId() || $this->getStatus() == self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED || $this->getStatus() == self::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE
        ) {
            if ($isConfirmNeed === true) {
                // if user subscribes own login email - confirmation is not needed
                $isOwnSubscribes = $isSubscribeOwnEmail;
                if ($isOwnSubscribes == true) {
                    $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
                } else {
                    $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE);
                }
            } else {
                $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
            }
            $this->setSubscriberEmail($email);
            $this->setSubscriberName($subscriber_name); //subscriber_name
            $this->setSubscriberDateofbirth($subscriber_date_of_birth); //date of birth
            $this->setSubscriberCountrycode($subscriber_country_code); //country code
        }

        if ($isSubscribeOwnEmail) {
            try {
                $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($this->_customerSession->getCustomerId());
                $this->setStoreId($customer->getStoreId());
                $this->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                $this->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
                $this->setCustomerId(0);
            }
        } else {
            $this->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
            $this->setCustomerId(0);
        }

        $this->setStatusChanged(true);

        try {
            $this->save();
            if ($isConfirmNeed === true && $isOwnSubscribes === false
            ) {
                $this->sendConfirmationRequestEmail();
            } else {
                $this->sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();
            }
            return $this->getStatus();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Delete the `pub/static` files expext .htaccess and `var/generation` files and the deploy static content. See the result again.

Comment: i have try this not working

Answer (score 9):

Finally i have resolve my issue .
Only Need to override Subscriber.
I am posting my entire code. may be it will helpful to someone.
di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber" type="Navin\Subscribe\Model\Subscriber" />
</config>
```

Subscriber.php Model Files

```
namespace Navin\Subscribe\Model;

class Subscriber extends \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber {

    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function subscribe($email, $subscriber_name = '', $subscriber_date_of_birth = '', $subscriber_country_code = '') {

        $this->loadByEmail($email);

        if (!$this->getId()) {
            $this->setSubscriberConfirmCode($this->randomSequence());
        }

        $isConfirmNeed = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                        self::XML_PATH_CONFIRMATION_FLAG, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                ) == 1 ? true : false;
        $isOwnSubscribes = false;

        $isSubscribeOwnEmail = $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn() && $this->_customerSession->getCustomerDataObject()->getEmail() == $email;

        if (!$this->getId() || $this->getStatus() == self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED || $this->getStatus() == self::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE
        ) {
            if ($isConfirmNeed === true) {
                // if user subscribes own login email - confirmation is not needed
                $isOwnSubscribes = $isSubscribeOwnEmail;
                if ($isOwnSubscribes == true) {
                    $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
                } else {
                    $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE);
                }
            } else {
                $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
            }

            $this->setSubscriberEmail($_POST['email']);

        }

        if(!empty($_POST['subscriber_name']) ){
                $this->setSubscriberName($_POST['subscriber_name']); //subscriber_name
                $this->setSubscriberDateofbirth($_POST['subscriber_dateofbirth']); //date of birth
                $this->setSubscriberCountrycode($_POST['subscriber_countrycode']); //country code
        }

        if ($isSubscribeOwnEmail) {
            try {
                $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($this->_customerSession->getCustomerId());
                $this->setStoreId($customer->getStoreId());
                $this->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                $this->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
                $this->setCustomerId(0);
            }
        } else {
            $this->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
            $this->setCustomerId(0);
        }

        $this->setStatusChanged(true);

        try {
            $this->save();
            if ($isConfirmNeed === true && $isOwnSubscribes === false
            ) {
                $this->sendConfirmationRequestEmail();
            } else {
                $this->sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();
            }
            return $this->getStatus();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: does this have email validation and return the status message. for example "'This email address is already assigned to another user.'" or "'Please enter a valid email address.'", etc?

Answer (score 0):

As the new controller extends the original controller, you need to extend its constructor instead of just overwriting it. Try using the code below for the constructor:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
    \Navin\Subscribe\Model\Subscriber $subscriberFactory
) {
    $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
    $this->subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $subscriberFactory,
        $customerSession,
        $storeManager,
        $customerUrl
    );
}
```

**And don't forget to clean 'var/generation' and 'var/di' folders after making the changes in the constructor.**

Comment: Not Working 
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\\Newsletter\\Controller\\Subscriber\\NewAction::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\\Newsletter\\Model\\SubscriberFactory, instance of Navin\\Subscribe\\Model\\Subscriber given

Answer (score 0):

I think, You missed Context Object, Try this below code.

add \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, to Constructor:

```
  namespace Navin\Subscribe\Controller\Subscribe;

      //use Navin\Subscribe\Model\SubscriberFactory;

      class NewAction extends \Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction {

          /**
           * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
           */
          protected $subscriberFactory;

          public function __construct(
          \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
          \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory
          \Navin\Subscribe\Model\Subscriber $subscriber,
           array $data = array()

          ) {
              $this->subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
              $this->subscriber = $subscriber;
              parent::__construct($context,
                        $subscriberFactory, 
                        $subscriber, 
                        $data);


          }

          public function execute() {

              //echo 'test come here';exit;
              $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
              //var_dump($post);exit;

              if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('email')) {
                  $email = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
                  $subscriber_name = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('subscriber_name');
                  $subscriber_date_of_birth = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('subscriber_dateofbirth');
                  $subscriber_country_code = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('subscriber_countrycode');
                  $requestCatalog = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('requestCatalog');

                  try {
                      $this->validateEmailFormat($email);
                      $this->validateGuestSubscription();
                      $this->validateEmailAvailable($email);

                      $status = $this->subscriberFactory->subscribe($email, $subscriber_name, $subscriber_date_of_birth, $subscriber_country_code);
                      if ($status == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                          $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The confirmation request has been sent.'));
                      } else {

                          $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Thank you for your subscription.'));
                      }
                  } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                      $this->messageManager->addException(
                              $e, __('There was a problem with the subscription: %1', $e->getMessage())
                      );
                  } catch (\Exception $e) {

                      $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong with the subscription.'));
                  }
              }

              $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl());
          }

      }
```

Comment: i have try . not working

Comment: @BhudiyaNavin, you got any error message.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\\Newsletter\\Controller\\Subscriber\\NewAction::__co‌​nstruct() must be an instance of Magento\\Newsletter\\Model\\SubscriberFactory, instance of Navin\\Subscribe\\Model\\Subscriber

Comment: @BhudiyaNavin I update my answer, try this then, tell me if you got any errors,

Comment: Now i am getting this error:
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare Navin\\Subscribe\\Controller\\Subscribe\\NewAction::$subscriberFactory in /var/www/html/jansport/app/code/Navin/Subscribe/Controller/Subscribe/NewAction.php on line 27, referer: http://45.33.122.66/jansport/